# A question to do with many users reading/writing the exact same xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, read-write, xml

I have created a website where a non-trivial number of users will be reading from and/or writing to a single XML file at the exact same time.

I am not asking for suggestions on an alternative to the current setup I just want to know if I was wrong with that approach or correct. If it was wrong to do it that way, please explain to me why that is wrong?

Comment: Use a database for that many concurrent users.

Comment: You need to `Split[',']` this question up into sentences.  It's nearly impossible to follow what your asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reads are sort-of fine.  You load the file into RAM, and it's plenty fast.  The only problem is stale data, but since we're just talking about reads at this point it's okay.

Writes are the real problem.  ***No one*** runs a serious web site using xml as the data store where there's potentially more than one writer (or at very most a handful) in the same file.  This is the problem a relational database (or even nosql database) was made to solve.  Look into sql server express edition instead (it's free).

Comment: Thanks allot. That was basically what I thought now that I know what I know. I was thinking that a db based system for this would be best.

The fact is that I set it up this way initially when I knew less about asp.net and c#, and xml files. I thought that that way would be the best, but after much experience, I realized that that system is most likely going to fail. So I asked this question on this day, and thank you sir (and others) for responding to this issue.

Comment: Anyways, I'm going to change all that code to adapt to this realization, it will take a little bit of time for me, but it's fine, I'm happy I realized this now. Thanks allot.

Comment: Actually, I just was thinking about it, and here's a follow-up question.

What about if it's just one user writing to a xml file at whatever time, as many times as he can, lets say once a minute or 2 at some points, while at the same time lets say 20 different users read the same file. Would that make sense? Or is that flawed as well? I'm not deffinate here, but I assume that it does make sense that way.

Comment: @AspCoder - it depends on the nature of the writes.